# utf8-bin to french word

Tags: java

i have data encoded with utf8-bin and i want to convert this data to french like this :
utf8-bin  ->  0x79756B686179796962
the result suppose to be french word  -> avorté
but i have this result  yukhayyib

```
    public String convertStringToHex(String str){

      char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

      StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
      for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int)chars[i]));
      }

      return hex.toString();
  }
```

kindly could any one tell me what is wrong and what is the steps to convert this encoded word to french word ?
thanks

Comment: Well, I've never heard of "UTF8-bin", and that's not UTF-8.  (At least not for "avorté".)

Comment: Are you sure you have given a correct example? Your code actually converts from text to hexadecimal.

Comment: these data comes from mysql database which support this kind of data .

Comment: I see that "utf8-bin" is a term in MySQL for case-sensitive text.  But, from a very brief reading, it should still be valid UTF8.

Comment: when i connect to mysql, i have the correct result but i don't want to connect to mysql i read these data from external file

Comment: But as DRCB says, the above code is to convert characters to hex, and wouldn't produce either "avorté" or "yukhayyib".

Comment: From *what* "external file".  Where did the file come from?

Comment: for me the result is "yukhayyib"

Answer (score 1):

To get UTF-8 from a String:

`byte[] bytes = "avorté".getBytes("UTF-8")`

To get a String from UTF-8:

`String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-8")`